# Excel index/match formula issue (List)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to write an index/match formula to return a list. The value of my list is a drop down of site codes. I am looking to return a list of "employee IDs" from a separate list. writing formulas is not my strong suite at all so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have provided snips for reference. I have blanked out personal info on the roster tab for privacy purposes.
[image]

[image]

```
=INDEX('TOM HR Roster'!$A:$B,(MATCH($B$3,'TOM HR Roster'!$A:$A,0)),MATCH('TOM HR Roster'!B1,'TOM HR Roster'!1:1,0))
```

Comment: Please enter your formula as text and not a screenshot, thanks!

Comment: In your example, the site code listed on worksheet TOM HR Roster is not unique per employee.  There is more than one employee with the same site code.  What addtl criteria do you intend to use to return a unique value?

Comment: =INDEX('TOM HR Roster'!$A:$B,(MATCH($B$3,'TOM HR Roster'!$A:$A,0)),MATCH('TOM HR Roster'!B1,'TOM HR Roster'!1:1,0))

Comment: I am trying to return an the entire list of "Employee ID" based on my site code. When I search a site code I want it to display the multiple employees linked to that site code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would use index/match to return the value of a column based on values from two other columns. Formatting your data as tables will make your formula more readable and less prone to errors.  The tables in this example are table_Fruit (blue) and table_IndexMatch (yellow).  We are looking up the values in the Fruit and Color columns of the IndexMatch table in the Fruit table and, if found, returning the corresponding ID.

[image]

This is the formula in cells E9:E14.  This is an array formula, so after you enter the formula, with the cursor still inside the cell, Ctrl + shift + enter.

```
=INDEX(table_Fruit,
MATCH(1,(table_Fruit[Fruit]=[@Fruit])*(table_Fruit[Color]=[@Color]),0)
,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer (and consider upvoting) if it has helped you.